# How to distinguish a Model Inadequacy from Mismeasured Variables?

Tags: modeling, measurement-error

From what I've read, theoretically both cases are very different.

In a mismeasured variables case, we're dealing with a error measurement models.
In a model inadequacy case, it's the model itself that isn't suitable, and we should either add an extra term to correct that inadequacy, or use a different model altogether.

We can have one without the other. If our variables were measured correctly, but our model had not taken in consideration some physical/medical(...) aspect/fact of our experiment, then our predictions would still be biased. Or our model can be correct, but we've measured with some error our variables(dependent or independent).

My question is how can we distinguish between both when modelling some process?How can I say that I'm in the presence of one, but not the other, or in both?

Any help would be appreciated.